# Checking for Required Field in Custom Vaildator

Tags: validation, jsf, composite-component, required

I've got a custom validator set up to run on the elements of a composite component.  It looks like this:

```
<myproject:myComponent>
    <f:validator validatorId="customValidator" for="validatedField" />
</myproject:myComponent>
```

And the composite component looks like this:

```
<composite:interface>
    <composite:editableValueHolder name="validatedField" targets="validatedField" />
</composite:interface>
<composite:implementation>
    <h:inputText id="validatedField" />
</composite:implementation>
```

It's working, mostly, but there's one hiccup: how do I designate a field as required?

It appears that, when I leave the validated field blank entirely, the custom validator doesn't get called at all.  I tried adding a `<f:validateRequired for="validatedField" />` inside the `mycomponent`, but it didn't work.

---

**Edit** (in response to BalusC):  A more detailed description of the context my composite component appears within:

```
<p:outputPanel id="pnlElements">
    <ui:repeat value="#{backingViewBean.elementDtos}" var="elementDto">
        <p:commandButton value="Edit..."
                         action="#{backingControllerBean.refreshView}"
                         ajax="true"
                         update=":frmMain:editElement"
                         oncomplete="wdgEditElement.show()">
            <f:setPropertyActionListener  
                             target="#higherLevelControllerBean.currentElementId}"
                             value="#{elementDto.Id}" />
        </p:commandButton>
    </ui:repeat>
</p:outputPanel>

<p:dialog widgetVar="wdgEditElement" modal="true">
    <p:outputPanel id="editElement">
        <myproject:myComponent>
            <f:validator validatorId="customValidator" for="validatedField" />
        </myproject:myComponent>
    </p:outputPanel>
</p:dialog>
```

The page displays a list of the elements I've created, with an edit button (and other stuff I'm omitting) for each.  Click the edit button, and a window pops-up containing the composite component (along with a save button, again omitted for clarity) where I can edit the element.

The problem is that, when I set `javax.faces.VALIDATE_EMPTY_FIELDS` to `true`, the validator gets called before the data object populating the edit window gets set, and it barks at me for having empty fields.  (And aborts execution before the data object gets set, so all the fields appear empty.)

(In addition, I notice that when that when `VALIDATE_EMPTY_FIELDS` is set to `false`, the second and subsequent times I click the Edit button also triggers a call to the validator.  This appears harmless, but isn't the behavior I was expecting.)

I'm running under Glassfish, so I'd expect `<f:validateRequired>` to be working -- so perhaps I'm using it wrong.  I was using it like this:

```
<myproject:myComponent>
    <f:validator validatorId="customValidator" for="validatedField" />
    <f:validateRequired for="validatedField" />
</myproject:myComponent>
```

Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Have you tried adding an attribute to your component with name "required" and passing along its value to the `h:inputText` as `required="#{cc.attrs.required}"`?

Comment: @elias:  Huh.  I was expecting that to flat-out not work (tinkering with validation inside of a composite component has not been a fruitful line of inquiry), but ... well, setting `required="true"` (I don't need it configurable -- that field is ALWAYS required) still didn't work, but not for the reasons I expected.  It wound up behaving as described in my edit above: the validator was called before the backing object was populated, so when I click the Edit button, I get an error message and a bunch of empty fields.  So thanks for giving me a new way to fail, at least.  :-)

Comment: Well, holy cow.  Putting a validator in the composite component now works!  Apparently, I was making another error (since corrected) that made me think that was a losing option.  Regardless, tucking the validator into the component and using the "required" attribute gives me exactly the behavior I want.

Comment: @BlairHipppo you could post an answer your question, expliciting what were your wrong assumptions and how you solved your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `<f:validateRequired>` works only if JSR303 bean validation is enabled in your web application (which is usually the case in Java EE web profile compatible servers, such as Glassfish, JBoss AS and TomEE, but thus not in simple servletcontainers like Tomcat). If your webapp doesn't have, then you need to manually force bean validation of empty fields as follows in `web.xml`:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.VALIDATE_EMPTY_FIELDS</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's still not working.  Please see my edits for more details.

Comment: So the dialog is in the same form as the edit button and thus also processed when edit button is pressed? Put the dialog outside that form and give the dialog its own form.

Comment: As to Glassfish matter, which version? Do you have `<f:validateBean disabled="true">` somewhere in the view?

Comment: Glassfish 3.1.2.  And the string "validateBean" doesn't appear anywhere inside the project, so no, doesn't look like it.

Comment: As to giving the dialog its own form, that sounds like a very fruitful approach and better architecture, too.  I'll refactor.

Comment: Handing you the checkmark because while this didn't QUITE fix it, it helped with the investigation that led to the actual solution, and led to a better implementation to boot.  Thanks for your assistance.